# AngularJS - HTTP request makes preflight request in controllers but not in app.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, cors, preflight

I have an app which communicates with an external API. My app has a controller for each page. If I make a HTTP GET request in one of my controllers, it sends an OPTIONS preflight request, and I receive an error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://dev/api/?email_address=email@email.com&password=111111. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

However, if I copy paste the same code and paste it in my app.js file, it works flawlessly and returns me the data. I found out that this way it also only sends the GET request, and not the OPTIONS request.

I have tried adding the header content type as "text/plain" to my requests but that changes nothing. If I try making the requests with jQuery it works well, sending only the GET request, not matter if the code is in the controller or in the app.js file. Here is the complete controller code (in Angular form):

```
angular.module('website.homepage', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'homepage/view.html',
        controller: 'HomepageCtrl',
        resolve: {
            data: function($q, $http, $route, $rootScope) {
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http({method: 'GET', url: $rootScope.apiURL + 'home'})
                    .then(function(data) {
                        deferred.resolve(data);
                    });
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        }
    })
}])
.controller('HomepageCtrl', function ($scope, $http, data) {

        var url = "http://dev.api";

        $http({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            method: "GET",
            data: '',
            params: {
                email_address: 'email@email.com',
                password: '111111'
            },
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
            }
        })
        .success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);

        })
       .error(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
       });


 })
 .config(function ( $httpProvider) {
     delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
 })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a research on the concept [*CORS*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) which stands for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing. CORS is a technique by means of which resources on one location on the Internet are allowed to be *requested* from other domains. 
As a security feature, cross-origin requests are forbidden by default due to a notion known as [same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

You are getting the error because you are trying to make a ***cross-origin*** request, which is, in fact, being disallowed.

Try to delete the header that Angular sends by default to *prevent* such requests:

```
angular.module('someModule') 
.config(function ( $httpProvider) {        
    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
})...
```

### Update

I think, there can be only *one* configuration block in a module. Therefore, you need to combine the two configurations you have into a single one:

```
angular.module('website.homepage', ['ngRoute'])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) { // inject the other provider here
$routeProvider.when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'homepage/view.html',
    controller: 'HomepageCtrl',
    resolve: {
        data: function($q, $http, $route, $rootScope) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $http({method: 'GET', url: $rootScope.apiURL + 'home'})
                .then(function(data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
      }
    });

    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}])...   // rest of your code (services, factories, whatever)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this still doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: What do you get in your console?

Comment: I get exactly the same issue as before. XMLHttpRequest cannot load  http://dev.api/?email_address=email@email.com&password=111111. Request header field Authorization is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: Did you delete that particular header in your Angular's `config` as pointed out? Please also share the error text that you get in your console (using Chrome with Angular is preferable for debugging).

Comment: Yes, I did. I edited my question to include the complete controller code. The error message was also updated, that is all I get in the console. Thanks.

Comment: @LuísFerreira, check the _Update_. I think there was a problem with your module's configuration block. See if it helps.

Comment: It still gives the same error. Maybe it's simpler to stick to jQuery. Thanks for the help and for your time! :)